# How to generate a column in a CSV file instead of a row

Tags: ruby, csv, spreadsheet

So what I'm trying to do is read a specific column from an existing CSV file, parse some information out of the pulled data, then make a new CSV file with the newly parsed information in a single column. The header and first entry of the generated array go into the CSV file correctly, but after those, every other entry goes into the adjacent cells of the same row instead of creating a column, so it's like an L shape instead of just a line. Any ideas?

```
#!ruby.exe
require 'csv'

puts "Please enter a file name:" #user input file name (must be in same 
folder as this file)
file = gets.chomp

begin
  File.open(file, 'r')
rescue
  print "Failed to open #{file}\n"
  exit
end #makes sure that the file exists, if it does not it posts an error

data_file = File.new(file)
data = [] #initializes array for addresses from .csv
counter=0 #set counter up to allow for different sized files to be used 
without issue

CSV.foreach(data_file, headers: true) do |row|
  data << row.to_hash
  counter+=1
end #goes through .csv one line ar a time

data.reject(&:empty?)

puts "Which column do you want to parse?"
column = gets.chomp

i=0

streets = []

while (i<counter)
  address = data[i][column]
  street_name = address.gsub(/^((\d[a-zA-Z])|[^a-zA-Z])*/, '')
  streets.push(street_name)
  i+=1
end

streets.reject(&:empty?)

puts "What do you want the output to be called?"
new_file = gets.chomp

CSV.open(new_file, "w", :write_headers=> true, :headers => [column]) do |hdr|
  hdr << streets
end
```

Comment: I suspect empty rows in `data` and `streets` - use `reject!` instead of `reject` to modify objects in place.

Comment: `hdr << streets` → `streets.each(&hdr.method(:<<))` should do.

Comment: Bartosz recommendation didn't change anything, and I got an 'unexpected tIDENTIFIER' error with mudasobwa's.

Comment: Try `CSV.generate_line(row)`. This is what I use in my project. More info here: https://apidock.com/ruby/CSV/generate_line/class

Comment: Been trying to figure out CSV.generate_line, but am not understanding the syntax in this context, but it seems to be exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should scan the street array and insert it as a row, which means you need to place the line of data into an array before to send to the csv. Ok, maybe the code is simpler than the explanation:

```
CSV.open(new_file, "w", :write_headers=> true, :headers => [column]) do |csv_line|
  streets.each { |street| csv_line << [street] }
end
```